# Error when trying to create Kubernetes deployment - Invalid spec.selector

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to create a kubernetes deployment. Here is the manifest:

`server-deployment.yaml`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: server-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      tier: server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        tier: server
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: rocketblast2481/chatto-server
          name: server-container
          imagePullPolicy: Always
```

Then I run the following command:

```
kubectl apply -f=server-deployment.yaml
```

But then I get the following error:

```
The Deployment "server-deployment" is invalid: spec.selector: Invalid value: v1.LabelSelector{MatchLabels:map[string]string{"tier":"server"}, MatchExpressions:[]v1.LabelSelectorRequirement(nil)}: field is immutabl
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to update deployment selector. Which is not possible. To update selector first delete existing deployment using.
kubectl delete deployment server-deployment
Then run
kubectl apply -f server-deployment.yml

Answer (score 1):

Once a deployment spec is deployed the [selector become immutable](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#label-selector-updates), this means you cannot change it by re-apply with updated spec.

> Note: In API version apps/v1, a Deployment's label selector is
> immutable after it gets created.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but Akshay's answer provided a way I could solve the problem, so I accepted his answer.